# symfony 4 upload without handleResquest method on form but with xhr object html

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, post, request

hello i want to execute my progressbar with xhr html request , simple submit with symfony 4 is not enough

i try to execute an xhr html request  on a php method with a form data , And to prevent event default with e.preventDefault() instruction but it doesn't work .I dont' know why Symfony toolbar say me it's ok (code 200).But i can't get the input file object with php .i post my code here.

```js
var uploadForm=document.getElementById("form2");
uploadForm.addEventListener("submit", uploadFile);
function uploadFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputFile=document.getElementById("user_file").files[0];
    let uploadDataForm = new FormData();
    uploadDataForm.append('file',inputFile);
    for (var value of uploadDataForm.values()) {
        console.log(value);
    }
 try {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/');
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e => {
            const percent = e.lengthComputable ? (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 : 0;
            progressBarFill.width = percent.toFixed(2)
            progressBarText.textContent=percent.toFixed(2);
        });
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.send(uploadDataForm);


    }
    catch (error){
        console.error(error);
    }





}
```

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="acceuil")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request,ProductManager $productManager)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = new User();
    $file = $request->query->get('file');
    try {
        /** @var UploadedFile $task */
        $task = $file;
        if ($task === null) exit;
        $destination = $this->getParameter('files_directory');
        $originalFilename = pathinfo($task->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $newFilename = Urlizer::urlize($originalFilename) . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $task->guessExtension();


        //$fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessClientExtension();
        $task->move(
            $destination,
            $newFilename
        // $this->getParameter('files_directory'),


        );
        return $this->redirectToRoute('acceuil');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

}

and i can't save my input file .

```html
   <div class="col-12">
    {{ form_start(form2,{'attr': {'id': 'form2'}})  }}
    {{ form_row(form2.file,{attr:{'placeholder':'veuillez importer votre CV'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form2) }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer!</button>
    {{ form_end(form2) }}
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar">
            <div class="progress-bar-fill">
                <span class="progress-bar-text">0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% if fichier is defined %}
        {%  for fich fichier %}
            <div>{{ fich }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

i have this error too
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.

```
    const progressBarFill = document.getElementsByClassName('progress');
const progressBarText = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
var uploadForm = document.getElementById("form2");
uploadForm.addEventListener("submit", uploadFile);
function uploadFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputFile=document.getElementById("user_file").files[0];
    let uploadDataForm = new FormData();
    uploadDataForm.append('file',inputFile);
    for (var value of uploadDataForm.values()) {
        console.log(value);
    }
    try {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/uploadAjax');
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e => {
            const percent = e.lengthComputable ? (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 : 0;
            $(".progress-bar").width(percent+ '%');
            $(".progress-bar").html(percent+'%');
        });

        xhr.send(uploadDataForm);




        console.log(response);
}




    }
    catch (error){
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

and php code :

```
     /**
     ** @Route("/uploadAjax", name="uploadAjax")
     * @param Request $uneRequete
     * @return void
     */
    public Function uploadAjax(Request $uneRequete){

            try {
                $test = 'c bon';
                $req = $uneRequete;

                /** @var UploadedFile $file */
                $file = $uneRequete->files->get('file');

                if ($file === null) exit;
                $destination = $this->getParameter('files_directory');
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $newFilename = Urlizer::urlize($originalFilename) . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

                //$fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessClientExtension();
                $file->move(
                    $destination,
                    $newFilename

                );
            }
            catch (\Exception$e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }


       return $this->render('acceuil/index.html.twig',['uneRequete'=>$req]);
    }
}
```